# Is "Host GPU on" on android emulator same as GPU passthrough?

Tags: graphics-card, virtualization, android

I see that there's "Host GPU on" for standard Android emulator(which is incidentally qemu-based) from Google. Is it same as the hardware acceleration obtained by successful GPU-passthrough in Qemu-kvm? I feel it's not entirely same as GPU passthrough as GPU passthrough is a daunting task as it's very difficult to get the right(host-kernel-version+host-kernel-config+host-GPU-driver+guest-kernel-version+guest-kernel-config+guest-userspace-graphics-driver) configuration supporting every brand/type of GPU out there in various laptop(very handful of GPUs have been successfully passed through via pci-assign and vfio-pci-assign as per information over [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162768)). Also, when we select "Host GPU on", does it have to be secondary GPU and what if there's only one primary GPU - will the hardware acceleration be disabled? Any thoughts in this regard?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I was investigating and experimenting with various options, etc
to get my Intel IGD passthru to work and at that point in time,
I had those questions. But, I have *successfully* completed
my Intel IGD passthru work with QEMU/KVM using Android-x86 5.1/Lollipop,
Windows 10 LTSB 64-bit, and Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. Interested ones,
watch the videos below!

### Successful Intel IGD GPU Passthru(primary) + QEMU/KVM + Android-x86 Virtualization :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBN1DmarJ7k

### Successful Intel IGD GPU Passthru(primary) + QEMU/KVM + Windows 10 LTSB 64-bit Virtualization :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmKzRGT2cjI

### Successful Intel IGD GPU Passthru(primary) + QEMU/KVM + Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit Virtualization :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_VXTDgqnHg

Cheers,

Raghavan